# webdriver-manager update command throwing error

Tags: protractor

Using the command webdriver-manager update throws the

```
events.js:160       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event       ^  
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.196.112:443     
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)     
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20) 
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14 )
```

and one thing to note is ,while running this command, dynamically the ip gets changed each and every time

Answer (score 0):

That looks like connection issue, try to ping ip 216.58.196.112:443 and see if it is accessible

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue, As you suggest pinged using the ip and getting "Destination net unreachable" message. If there any way to resolve the issue.